Add Sort Order option to Users column data in WooCommerce
I am trying to figure out a way to add custom sorting - asc / desc to the following code which I have added to functions.php to a WooCommerce store.
The code adds a column with the total placed orders for each user/customer in the Users admin section of WooCommerce, however the sorting functionality is missing.
The code has been tested and shows correctly the number of orders a user has made. The only functionality it is lacking is sorting by number of orders - ascending or descending.
Code is below:
 add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_new_user_column' );

function add_new_user_column( $columns ) {

$columns['placed_order'] = 'Orders Placed';

return $columns;

}

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'add_new_user_column_content', 10, 3 );

function add_new_user_column_content( $content, $column, $user_id ) {

if ( 'placed_order' === $column ) {

$customer_orders = get_posts( array(

'numberposts' => -1,

'meta_key' => '_customer_user',

'meta_value' => $user_id,

'post_type' => wc_get_order_types(),

'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),

) );

$store_products = wp_list_pluck( $customer_orders, 'ID' );

$content = count($store_products);

}

return $content;}

Would love and appreciate if you have a clue how to incorporate it!
Thank you in advance.

You can use the manage_{$this->screen->id}_sortable_columns filter hook to make your column sortable. (WP Documentation)
You will probably need to use it in combination with pre_get_users action to apply sorting to the query.
